# Find a fault in this counting proof

Tags: probability, combinatorics, solution-verification, combinations

> An urn contains $5$ red, $5$ black and $10$ white balls. If balls are drawn without replacement, what is the probability that in first 7 draws, at least one ball of each colour is drawn?

This problem is easy  to solve using inclusion-exclusion, but let's use a different approach this time.

Say , I choose $n_1, n_2,n_3$ red, black and white balls respectively.
So, by the problem : $n_1+n_2+n_3 =7$.
Our favourable case requires $n_1 > 0, n_2>0, n_3>0$, so, take $n_{i} ' = n_{i}-1 $ for $i=1,2,3$.
So, now, $ 0 \le n_1' \le 4  ; 0 \le n_2 ' \le 4 ; 0 \le n_3 ' \le 9$
So, number of favourable cases is $\displaystyle \sum_{n_1 ' + n_2 ' + n_3 ' =4} {4 \choose n_1 '}{4 \choose n_2 '}{9 \choose n_3 '}={17 \choose 4}$ which is a lot less than the number of cases given in the solution of this problem$( 64650)$.

What is the snag in this proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your sum for the favourable cases only counts the ones where the fifth red ball, the fifth black ball and the tenth white ball are all chosen (you have counted all the cases where you choose $n'_1$ of the first four reds, etc, so this assumes the remaining red ball chosen is the other one). There are many other favourable cases.

Comment: So, you are suggesting that since the balls are distinguishable, it does matter which 3 balls are chosen first meaning which red ball, which black ball and which white ball?

Comment: @MathsFreak Not exactly. It matters which $n_1$ red balls you choose. It doesn't matter which of those you designate as the "first" one and which you designate as the "other $n'_1$" (and if you try counting all combinations with one designated "first" you will overcount). But it does matter that if $n_1=2$, say, you count all $\binom 52=10$ options; your attempt currently only counts $4$ of them, which correspond to the options including a specific one.

Comment: okay got it thanks